# Typescript: Infer based on generics

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

When placing a type guard for `arg1` I'd expect `arg2` to be inferred automatically, but it doesn't.

Anyone an idea why this isn't working? what's the best alternative? Thanks so much!

You can see the types in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgHgBUVUpkwATAZ0QHJg447EAfegI3QCc6A%20ABQ8A5gEYAXIiIAaRCIBMkkmnJVaDJiwD8ialG4wwwxJLAhMHZNwCUiAN4AoRIhjBEQ7mMQBeX-UbMto7OzgqIAPThugAWcCC4lIiWuvqGwlpOiAC%20Dpmu7iKiPn50XLxBmaGe8hFR1LHxiclmFlYZzjlZQA). Simply hover over `arg2` to see the inferred type.

```
function example<T extends 'foo' | 'bar'>(
  arg1: T, 
  arg2: T extends 'foo' ? string : number
) {
  if (arg1 === 'foo') {
    arg2 // should be string?
  }

  if (arg1 === 'bar') {
    arg2 // should be number?
  }
}
```

However, invoking the function does correctly apply the second arg type:

[image]

[image]

Here's another example using a typed object based on generics:

```
type Test <T extends boolean> = {
  multiple: T;
  value: T extends true ? string : number;
};

// this doesn't work?
function test <T extends boolean>(a: Test<T>) {
  if (a.multiple) {
    a.value // string | number?
  }else{
    a.value // string | number?
  }
}

// this works!
function test2 (a: Test<true> | Test<false>) {
  if (a.multiple) {
    a.value // is string
  }else{
    a.value // is number
  }
}
```

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoB4ZQgD2BAdgE3igCMB7EgGwgEMcA%20KAXigG8AoKKAWwFdzgBLMJQBcsANzsoANyrluEUWkzZ8hYACd5UAPxRE6-jgDmUUTm6ciEdRIC%20E1gHpHUYAAt%20hPCQQ4A5EgA7iTqANbarABm3DgAxgIkOK4ISKjoWLgExGSUNLQAFFSKKai0AJQskvyRUIUAdDx8gpQVbBwcVHUychCSthDk8BBt7Z3d8n2stqxOLnj8QSGh8ACEUTHx-InJiABMtUWwJRry9AA%20R4jIkbJD5ZUc1QcNvAJCEK2SHV2yExz9g2GXygY1%20vX%20UyAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these 2 solutions to have conditional arguments:

**Solution 1 (recommended)**: Use object for arguments

```
type Args = { arg1: 'foo'; arg2: string } | { arg1: 'bar'; arg2: number };
function example(args: Args): void {
  if (args.arg1 === 'foo') {
    args.arg2; // It's string
  }
  if (args.arg1 === 'bar') {
    args.arg2; // It's number
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**: Use arguments object

```
type Args = ['foo', string] | ['bar', number];
function example(...args: Args): void {
  if (args[0] === 'foo') {
    args[1]; // It's string
  }
  if (args[0] === 'bar') {
    args[1]; // It's number
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Union types seems to work fine (object or tuple), but it doesn’t seem to work with generics.

Conclusion: what I try to achieve seems to be impossible. Hopefully this will be supported in a future typescript release. 

Thanks!

Comment: Although my question hasn't really been answered, I find this answer the most clear

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this snippet:

```
const k = 'foo' as 'foo' | 'bar'

example(k, 'abc') // compiles ok
example(k, 1) // compiles ok
```

`arg2` is not tightly coupled with `arg1`. Still when you call `example` with a literal string: `'foo'` or `'bar'` as `arg1` Typescript can restrict type of `arg1` and infer exact type of `arg2`. But in general case this is not possible.

As a possible fix you could restrict args of `example`, like that:

```
function example2(...args: ['foo', string] | ['bar', number]) {
  if (args[0] === 'foo') {
    const s = args[1] // string
  }

  if (args[0] === 'bar') {
    const n = args[1] // number
  }
}
example2('foo', '') // ok
example2('bar', 0) // ok
example('foo', 0) // error
example2(k, 'abc') // error
example2(k, 1) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgHgBUVUpkwATAZ0QHJg447EAfegI3QCc6A+ABQ8A5gEYAXIiIAaRCIBMkkmnJVaDJiwD8ialG4wwwxJLAhMHZNwCUiAN4AoRIhjBEQ7mMQBeX-UbMto7OzgqIAPThugAWcCC4lIiWuvqGwlpOiAC+Dpmu7iKiPn50XLxBmaGe8hFR1LHxiclmFlYZzjk5DpGIALT9LtTUIMh9-Q4QCHqIANY+-ppy6gEs7KU8dLloWHjIAjOydOgcEHS2PZM4MPi0cDMO2zj4+7Ki51GX2NfIt-fdUf1eohsHAhjAOPhEMAYKgxr0HKBILAEKQdvh5AIAHTYkTUSQAbQ0zFkegMRgAumxEISynRZC1LNxyRVnPkPMJqPiAAyU3zeBaBeyVRCTMDTWj83H40SUnqktKZLqstzszk84r89blIUhEVTKCIJCSzycmW1Q3mRmKhxdR67DFEun0M7mu4PDBPZAO2myLnWd1ovaO33vFDcbhwbgBz0Yg70Y6nUNWCNRu3ol6IN7m5ORoA)

Situation with `type Test<T extends boolean>` is very similar. The definition of type does not restrict strictly enough possible values. For example:

```
const v1: Test<boolean> = {
  multiple: true,
  value: 'a'
}

const v2: Test<boolean> = {
  multiple: true,
  value: 1
}
```

Using `Test<true> | Test<false>` makes use of literal type and restricts set of possible values.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoB4ZQgD2BAdgE3igCMB7EgGwgEMcA+KAXigG8AoKKAWwFdzgBLMJQBcsANzsoANyrluEUWkzZ8hYACd5UAPxRE6-jgDmUUTm6ciEdRIC+E1gHpHUYAAt+hPCQQ4A5EgA7iTqANbarABm3DgAxgIkOK4ISKjoWLgExGSUNLQAFFSKKai0AJQskvyRUIUAdDx8gpQVbBwcVHUychCSthDk8BBt7Z3d8n2stqxOLnj8QSGh8ACEUTHx-InJiABMtUWwJRry9AA+R4jIkbJD5ZUc1QcNvAJCEK2SHV2yExz9g2GXygY1+vX+UxmsUSiGkAEZildSBRqHRGA8uK9mgpXJoIAAaSTjHF+Kh+SGsaE4WFSXaI4DIZG5NFMEaNN4iXHyQkcYmiOEUoA)

Comment: Thanks @artur-grzesiak! I'm aware that it works with union types, however this not really answers the question why generics aren't working as expected. 

Honestly I'm baffled that it doesn't work with generics in the actual function implementation. There should be enough information for TS to know the value (in type guards).

Comment: @codemirror Hmm, `arg1` might be of type `'foo'` or `'foo' | 'bar'`. Only in case of `'foo'` it restricts type of `arg2` to `string`. As I showed, it is possible to call your `example` function with `'foo'` and a number, so when you check for `arg1 === 'foo'` you cannot be sure `arg2` is a string.

Comment: Thanks! So type guard based on a generic (inferred) value seems to be impossible, only union types will work (like in your answer). Honestly, it’s still not clear to me “why” this isn’t possible, but at least I now know the only way to solve it is with union types (or with function overloads).